# SQLite database.query() returns 0

Tags: android, sqlite

Problem: a query of a table created in the SQLite Database Browser returns `0`.

Steps taken:

1) Created a table:

```
create table friends (id integer primary key, name TEXT, email TEXT, phone NUMERIC);
```

2) Populated the table (manually).

3) Attempted to select all from the table:

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lab5.db";
  String[] columns = new String[] {
              KEY_ROWID, 
              KEY_NAME, 
              KEY_EMAIL, 
              KEY_PHONE };   
    Cursor allRows = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Result: all Rows returns 0 rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: after getting cursor . try cursor.moveToFirst() and then check.

Comment: check your KEY_NAME value is it "name"?

Comment: There is no data, even though you say there is. The table is created and the query is syntactically correct because there's no exception.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have created a table using different names i.e you have not used String Key values while creating Table. And while fetching data you are trying to fetch the columns using the String key values which may be differing from the actual Columns names.

So better use the actual names of columns besides keys as `KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PHONE` try to fetch columns details as below:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {
          id, 
          name, 
          email, 
          phone};
```

Also change your database table name as actual table name as below:

```
 Cursor allRows = db.query("friends", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```